# Sorting a Database structure in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, sorting, structure

I have this structure:

```
Module Global_Variables
    Public myrecords(10) As myDatabase
    Public counter As Integer = 0

    Public Structure myDatabase
        'creates database Structure For input data
        <VBFixedString(30)> _
        Dim Driver As String           '30 bytes
        Dim Car As Integer             '4 bytes
        <VBFixedString(15)> _
        Dim Team As String             '15 bytes
        Dim Grid As Integer            '4 bytes
        Dim FastestLap As Double       '8 bytes
        Dim RaceTime As Double         '4 bytes
        Dim Points As Double           '4 bytes

    End Structure
End Module
```

The program receives data from the user and then displays the data in a text box called `txtOutput` in another form:

```
myrecords(counter).Driver = driver_box.Text
myrecords(counter).Car = car_box.Text
myrecords(counter).Team = team_box.Text
myrecords(counter).Grid = grid_box.Text
myrecords(counter).FastestLap = fl_box.Text
myrecords(counter).RaceTime = rt_box.Text
myrecords(counter).Points = points_box.Text

Form_Display.txtDisplay.AppendText(myrecords(counter).Driver & "          " & 
    myrecords(counter).Car & "          " & myrecords(counter).Team & "          " & 
    myrecords(counter).Grid & "             " & myrecords(counter).FastestLap & "             " & 
    myrecords(counter).RaceTime & "          " & myrecords(counter).Points & vbCrLf)

counter = counter + 1
MsgBox("Submit success!")
Call input_box_clear()
```

The user can then click a button to sort the records in ascending order by fastest lap. How do I do this?

I have tried algorithms such as bubble sort and selection sort but neither worked.

Thank you

Comment: RULE #1: Do not declare `Structure` types larger than 16 bytes. Anything >16 - declare a class.

Comment: Use LINQ and you will never need to write your own algorithm

Comment: Also take a look at `String.Format()` as a better option for building your display string.

Comment: @T.S. Normally I agree, but the use of `VBFixedString` indicates he may be relying on an API that requires a structure.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I doubt it. He seem trying to learn to align records. May be better use padding

Comment: Have you tried loading the data into DataGridView control?  It has options to sort the data by any column. You wouldn't necessarily need a custom type.  You load the data directly to a DataTable and use that as the DataSource for the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring type (class, not structure)

```
Public class RaceData
    Public Property Driver As String
    Public Property Car As Integer
    Public Property Team As String
    Public Property Grid As Integer
    Public Property FastestLap As Double
    Public Property RaceTime As Double
    Public Property Points As Double
End Class
```

In-memory database (look what is in System.Collections)

```
Private _raceDb As New List(Of RaceData)()
```

Add user input

```
Dim newItem As New RaceData()
newItem.Driver = driver_box.Text
newItem.Car = Integer.Parse(car_box.Text)
newItem.Team = team_box.Text
newItem.Grid = Integer.Parse(grid_box.Text)
newItem.FastestLap = Double.Parse(fl_box.Text)
newItem.RaceTime = Double.Parse(rt_box.Text)
newItem.Points = Double.Parse(points_box.Text)
_raceDb.Add(newItem)
```

Sorting for the grid (Read about LINQ)

```
// sort by fastest race time
Dim sortedDb As List(Of RaceData) = _raceDb.OrderBy(Function(x) x.RaceTime).ToList()
```

Pick one fastest race

```
Dim fastest As RaceData = _raceDb.OrderBy(Function(x) x.RaceTime).FirstOrDefault()
If fastest IsNot Nothing Then ...
```

Build a string for each item to add to multi-line textbox

```
Dim lines() As String = _raceDb.Select(Function(x) x.Driver & " --- " & x.Team).ToArray()
' Using some tips from the comments
Dim lines() As String = _raceDb.
    Select(Function(x) string.Format("{0,-30} --- {1,15}", x.Driver, x.Team)).ToArray()
```